# How to display 10000 digits in Eclipse console?

Tags: java, console, biginteger

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i =0; i<8000; i++){
        sb.append("5");
    }


    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(sb.toString());
    System.out.println(bi);
```

I'm unable to display such a huge number on console(Using eclipse). Also, getting timeout for huge numbers. Kindly help in displaying huge numbers on console.

Answer (score 5):

In preferences of Eclipse, Go to

```
Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console
```

uncheck the option

```
 "Limit console output"
```

That allows you to print unlimited lines. If you want to limit to some lines ...Use the option

```
"Console buffer size"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Suresh. Still unable to get them displayed by changing the settings. Can I improve my code to display huge numbers?

P.S., I'm solving https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-the-beast

Comment: You are welcome. mark it answer, it it's useful :) Have a good day.